# Seção frameworks do project.json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Em projetos ASP.NET 5 o arquivo `project.json` contém alguns dados importantes do projeto como dependências em outros pacotes. Acontece que esse arquivo tem uma seção "frameworks" que em projetos criados no VS fica da seguinte forma:

```
{
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    }
}
```

Agora eu não entendi exatamente o que isso significa. Eu sei que agora existem diferentes versões do CLR que podem ser usadas, tem o .NET completo e tem o Core CLR que é mais leve. Mas nessa seção tem basicamente "dnx451" e "dnxcore50" e eu não entendi muito bem isso.

Meu entendimento é o seguinte: a ideia é ter uma seção na qual para cada runtime no qual o projeto possa rodar seja possível dar configurações específicas? Então por exemplo, ao colocar "dnx451" eu estou definindo que o projeto pode rodar no .NET completo e ao colocar "dnxcore50" eu estou definindo que o projeto também pode rodar no Core CLR?

E então nos objetos correspondentes ao "dnx451" e ao "dnxcore50" a ideia é colocar configurações específicas para quando a aplicação roda nesse runtime? Por exemplo, dependencias que devem ser consideradas só ao usar um dos dois?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Eu sei que agora existem diferentes versões do CLR que podem ser usadas, tem o .NET completo e tem o Core CLR que é mais leve. Mas nessa seção tem basicamente "dnx451" e "dnxcore50" e eu não entendi muito bem isso.

`dnx451` é a seção para frameworks relacionados ao desenvolvimento Desktop. `dnxcore50` é para a CLR em geral.

### Meu entendimento é o seguinte: a ideia é ter uma seção na qual para cada runtime no qual o projeto possa rodar seja possível dar configurações específicas?

Sim.

### Então por exemplo, ao colocar "dnx451" eu estou definindo que o projeto pode rodar no .NET completo e ao colocar "dnxcore50" eu estou definindo que o projeto também pode rodar no Core CLR?

Não exatamente. Você está dizendo ao aplicativo como ele deve trabalhar **dependendo do ambiente**. Como eu disse ali pra cima, se você define bibliotecas na parte de `dnx451`, a ideia é que você esteja especificando a parte de Desktop, especificamente. A parte de Core CLR é que seria o lugar comum para outros ambientes.

#### E então nos objetos correspondentes ao "dnx451" e ao "dnxcore50" a ideia é colocar configurações específicas para quando a aplicação roda nesse runtime? Por exemplo, dependencias que devem ser consideradas só ao usar um dos dois?

Sim, exatamente. Configurações específicas para cada ambiente.

O `dnxcore50` seria para tudo. O `dnx451` para Desktop. Possivelmente novos ambientes podem surgir, mas sem precisar alterar a especificação.

As minúcias da configuração [estão aqui](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file).